# Swift: UIImagePickerController - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: xcode, swift

I'am trying to use the UIImagePickerController to take a image in my app. The view loads correct and the method after taking the picture gets called correctly. But in my method I get the following error when I trie to use the taken image. The error appears in the line where I set the **UIImage** to my **UIImageView**.

```
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is my method:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage pickerImage: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    var insertViewControllerStoryboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InsertViewController");
    self.showViewController((insertViewControllerStoryboard as InsertViewController), sender: insertViewController);

    insertViewController.imageView.image = pickerImage;

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

When I log the variable **pickerImage** the variable is not nil. The variable is filled with an UIImage. Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    ....

    var pickerImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    insertViewController.imageView.image = pickerImage;
```

Comment: Hmm i use this several times in my app and works great. Try to set the Image first beforee use: self.showViewController((insertViewControllerStoryboard as InsertViewController), sender: insertViewController);

Comment: No that does not work too. In my **InsertViewController** my imageView is an IBOutlet declared like this (maybe here the error?):

@IBOutlet var imageView:UIImageView!;

Comment: Try to create a simple variable in your insertViewController. For Example "image as UIImage" - set the value to image and use ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear to set the image to your ImageView.

Comment: No :( I tried to create an imageview and add it as subview to the current view and that worked. After that I tried a global variable and that worked too. For now, this works :) Really strange why this didn't work. But thank you for your help! :)